# Adding item to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array list of Fleets (Each fleet will hold its own list of Trucks).

I have a fleet class with the constructor

```
public Fleet(String businessName){
    this.businessName = businessName;
    this.fleetList = new ArrayList<Truck>();
}
```

So:

In my TUI, I have a helper method called createFleet. When the user presses 1 on the menu, it asks for a name of his business, and then makes a fleet named that. That method is:

```
public static void createFleet(){
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the fleet.");
    inputText = scan.nextLine();

    fleetCollection.add(new Fleet(inputText));
    printFleets();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("--- Fleet: " + inputText + " added ---");
    System.out.println("");
}
```

And my problem is that when I add one Fleet, and print the results I get:

```
Fleet 0: Fleet Number One
```

But when I add Fleet Number One, then press 1 on the menu again to add ANOTHER fleet (named Fleet Number Two) and print the fleet list, the results are:

```
Fleet 0: Fleet Number Two
Fleet 1: Fleet Number Two
```

It seems to be confusing the two...and this further breaks the program when I try to add trucks to the fleet, because It cannot pick the "right" fleet.

Please let me know if you need any other of my code.
I just need this to correctly add and print the fleets in the fleet list:

```
private static ArrayList<Fleet> fleetCollection;
```

Thank you :) for all the help!

Comment: can you post code of printFleets() method?

Comment: Hey man.... where is your question??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably declared `businessName` in Fleet class `static`, if so then remove it

Comment: In that case,`getBusinessName()` should be **NOT** static too

Comment: remove method modifier `static` of `getBusinessName()`

Comment: remove method modifier `static` of `fleetList`

Comment: use `fleet.getBusinessName()`  instead of `Fleet.getBusinessName();` // use `fleet` object, do not use as static

Answer (score 3):

You need to be clear about use of `static`

**static variable**

- It is a variable which belongs to the class and not    to object(instance)
- Static variables are initialized only once , at    the start of the execution . These variables will be initialized    first, before the initialization of any instance variables
- A single    copy to be shared by all instances of the class
- A static variable can    be accessed directly by the class name and doesn’t need any object
- Syntax : `<class-name>.<variable-name>`

**static method**

- It is a method which belongs to the class and not to the object(instance)
- A static method can access only static data. It can not access non-static data (instance variables)
- A static method can  call only  other static methods and can not call a non-static method from it.
- A static method  can be accessed directly by the class name and doesn’t need any object
- Syntax : `<class-name>.<method-name>`
- A static method cannot refer to "`this`" or "`super`"  keywords in anyway

src : http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-static-variable-methods.html

Answer (score 2):

have you overridden the equals method in Fleet ? if so and it's not correct, it could be the cause of your weird result

Comment: you need an instance from that class to be able to call a non-static method; like this: Object a = new Object(); a.method();

Comment: Should I open a new question for that problem? Or should I erase everything above, and post the new question here?

Answer (score 1):

I made small modifications to your program to make it simple.

```
class Fleet{
String businessName;
public Fleet(String businessName)
{ this.businessName = businessName;}
public String getBusinessName()
{
    return businessName;
}
}

public class T {
private static ArrayList<Fleet> fleetCollection = new ArrayList<Fleet>();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        createFleet("A");
         printFleets();
         createFleet("B");
        printFleets();
    }
     public static void createFleet(String name){
    System.out.println("");
    fleetCollection.add(new Fleet(name));
}
public static void printFleets(){
    Iterator i = fleetCollection.iterator();
    Fleet f;
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        f = (Fleet)i.next();
        System.out.println(f.getBusinessName());
    }
}

}
```

It prints as expected.

```
A

A
B
```

Check your access modifiers on "businessName" field. It shouldn't be static. Also check printFleets() method.

Comment: Thank you :) It now returns the fleets properly but my addTruck() is still broken.